# Myadmin Union error 1064

Tags: sql, union, union-all

I'm working on a query, it is working on a live page, but when I try it on the SQL from Myadmin, I get an 1064 error.

```
(
(SELECT bk_boekingen_kenmerk, bk_boekingen_naam, bk_boekingen_soort, bk_boekingen_datum, bk_locatie_naam 
FROM bk_boekingen_versie1 bk1 
JOIN bk_locatie loc ON bk1.bk_boekingen_locatie_id=loc.bk_locatie_id 
WHERE bk1.bk_boekingen_datum>='1399500000' 
AND bk1.bk_boekingen_status != '20' ) 
UNION 
(SELECT bk_boekingen_kenmerk, bk_boekingen_naam, bk_boekingen_soort, bk_boekingen_datum, bk_locatie_naam 
FROM bk_boekingen_versie2 bk2 
JOIN bk_locatie loc ON bk2.bk_boekingen_locatie_id=loc.bk_locatie_id 
WHERE bk2.bk_boekingen_datum>='1399500000' 
AND bk2.bk_boekingen_status != '20' ) 
UNION 
(SELECT bk_boekingen_kenmerk, bk_boekingen_naam, bk_boekingen_soort, bk_boekingen_datum, bk_locatie_naam 
FROM bk_boekingen_versie3 bk3 
JOIN bk_locatie loc ON bk3.bk_boekingen_locatie_id=loc.bk_locatie_id 
WHERE bk3.bk_boekingen_datum>='1399500000' 
AND bk3.bk_boekingen_status != '20' ) 
ORDER BY bk_boekingen_datum ASC
)
```

error code

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION (SELECT bk_boekingen_kenmerk, bk_boekingen_naam, bk_boekingen_soort, bk' at line 7
```

Comment: Probably the wrapping parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry I tried to remove them, but there remains the same.
Even tried a simple one like this:
code
    (
    SELECT bk_boekingen_kenmerk
 FROM bk_boekingen_versie1  
 WHERE bk_boekingen_datum>='1399500000' 
 UNION 
SELECT bk_boekingen_kenmerk
 FROM bk_boekingen_versie2  
 WHERE bk_boekingen_datum>='1399500000' 
 )

Comment: Try the entire query as posted in my answer and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like below

```
select * from
(
    SELECT bk_boekingen_kenmerk, 
    bk_boekingen_naam, 
    bk_boekingen_soort, 
    bk_boekingen_datum, 
    bk_locatie_naam 
    FROM bk_boekingen_versie1 bk1 
    JOIN bk_locatie loc ON bk1.bk_boekingen_locatie_id=loc.bk_locatie_id 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT bk_boekingen_kenmerk, 
    bk_boekingen_naam, 
    bk_boekingen_soort, 
    bk_boekingen_datum, 
    bk_locatie_naam 
    FROM bk_boekingen_versie2 bk2 
    JOIN bk_locatie loc ON bk2.bk_boekingen_locatie_id=loc.bk_locatie_id        
    UNION ALL       
    SELECT bk_boekingen_kenmerk, 
    bk_boekingen_naam, 
    bk_boekingen_soort, 
    bk_boekingen_datum, 
    bk_locatie_naam 
    FROM bk_boekingen_versie3 bk3 
    JOIN bk_locatie loc ON bk3.bk_boekingen_locatie_id=loc.bk_locatie_id 
) tab
    WHERE bk_boekingen_datum >='1399500000' 
    and bk_boekingen_status != '20'
    ORDER BY bk_boekingen_datum ASC
```

Comment: @Coolen, yes it's the derived table name. well, you can give any name.

Comment: @Coolen, did it worked? If yes, then don't forget to mark it as answer by clicking the check button below voting button.

Comment: It almost works sorry trying to find the problem (have to learn it sometimes ;-)
I get this error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @Coolen, did you used the entire query (OR) did you removed that `tab`? I am sure you have removed that `tab` after `)` and so the error is